# Vertical alignment without knowing height in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I would normally use absolute positioning and set the top to 50% with a negative margin-top (half of the child's height) to center vertically. In this case that will not work because the child element's height will vary.

So is there a way to vertically center a div within a div without knowing the child's height?

Comment: I believe SO was made to be specific to programmers unlike Google :)

Comment: Look at this answer in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206640/css-vertically-align-div-when-no-fixed-size-of-the-div-is-known

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use padding top , padding bottom to center elements vertically , with or without height definitions ...

Comment: I don't think padding will work if the height of the element changes, the only CSS solution is to use table-cell, or you can use javascript

Comment: Using the display:table-cell solution still uses div's, see http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Answer (score 5):

The following jquery function centers vertically assuming the item you are positioning is already position absolute and the parent position relative

```
$.fn.vAlign = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).css('top', '50%').css('margin-top', -Math.ceil($(this).height() / 2) + "px");
    });
};
```

View in action - http://jsfiddle.net/vqbMU/2/

**UPDATE:**

A pure CSS solution for browsers supporting css transforms (IE9+) http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

```
.align-v {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make the element display: table-cell and put vertical-align:center. I don't usually recommend using display: table- but that's the easiest solution I think

Answer (score 1):

You can also grab the child's height easily enough with JavaScript dynamically, and even easier with a JS library like jQuery.

According to your profile, you do have some familiarity with jQuery, so I would suggest that route.  If you need help with that solution let me know.