# CSS: Vertically align div when no fixed size of the div is known

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

How do I align a `<div>` which contains an image (or flash) vertically with CSS.  Height and width are dynamic.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div

Comment: have you tried anything yet? [http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html)

Comment: yes, I did but they are doing it only for cases when they know height... Also it doesn't work for me

Comment: Are all the heights dynamic and unknown? For the image/flash and for it's container? Must it be absolute positioned or placed near some content, or positioned relative to the viewport?

Comment: I am trying to center content on this page http://best-games-house.com/play/35/red-riot/ (for any play full screen on the site)

Comment: @pinouchon The questions are not duplicates. They ask 2 different things, despite the similar wording.

Comment: Vertically align how? Middle align?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is a pure CSS2 solution for horizontally and vertically centering without known sizes of either container nor child. No hacks are involved. I discovered it for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084305/position-badge-over-corner-of-image-automatically/6086386#6086386) and I also demonstrated it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180034/problem-vertically-aligning-text-of-an-element-that-spans-two-lines/6245662#6245662).

[The solution](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/t8VUL/) is based on `vertical-align: middle` in conjunction with `line-height: 0`, which parent has a fixed line-height.

The HTML:

```
<span id="center">
    <span id="wrap">
        <img src="http://lorempixum.com/300/250/abstract" alt="" />
    </span>
</span>
```

And the CSS:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#center {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1000px;
    height: 2000px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2000px;
}    
#wrap {
    line-height: 0;
}
#wrap img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Tested on Win7 in IE8, IE9, Opera 11.51, Safari 5.0.5, FF 6.0, Chrome 13.0.

The only caveat is IE7, for which the two innermost elements have to declared at one line, as demonstrated [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/t8VUL/1/):

```
<span id="center">
    <span id="wrap"><img src="http://lorempixum.com/300/250/abstract" alt="" /></span>
</span>
```

Note that the span's are also required for IE7. In every other browser, the span's may be div's.

Comment: Nicely done.  This is exactly what many people are looking for, including myself. Definitely the cleanest workaround for people who need to support ie7 [sigh]  I edited your fiddle to show another practical example .   http://jsfiddle.net/ryanore/R7szX/2/

Comment: wait how is this an answer.... so basically I get to vertically align, but I lose the ability to scroll my page (overflow: hidden on html,body)

Comment: @xckpd7 Of course it doesn't have to be the body; you can use this solution on any container element as [shown here](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/t8VUL/323/).

Comment: Thanks! I made some alterations which (1) make textual content look okay (2) center the content in respect to an element besides the body (3) use classes instead of ids so it's reusable. http://jsfiddle.net/sparebytes/q9sfQ/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sparebytes/q9sfQ/1/ - Added an animation to show its behavior

Comment: Useless for aligning block elements as pop-ups.

Comment: @NGLN why did you use `height` and `line-height` `2000px`?

Comment: @Rupam That's an arbitrary value. It would be the "maximum" height a device could display.

Answer (score 12):

You can do this by using inline-blocks, one with `height: 100%` (and same heights for `HTML` and `BODY`) and `vertical-align: middle`.

Example 1: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/TQX9b/ (a lot of content, so it's full width)

Example 2: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/TQX9b/2/ (an image with any size)

In this example I use `span`s, so It would work in IE without hacks, if you'd like to use `div`s, don't forget to add in Conditional Comments for IE `.helper, .content { display: inline; zoom: 1; }`, so inline-blocks would work for block elements.

Comment: Quite nice, but when the browser window narrows, the content moves to the "next line". Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Ah, yeah, since it's `inline-blocks`, you can use `white-space: nowrap` to prevent this: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/TQX9b/3/

Comment: Nice! You can also skip the `html` and `body` styles if you use another wrapper with `height: 100%;` and `position: absolute;` http://jsfiddle.net/TQX9b/256/ and `position: fixed;` http://jsfiddle.net/TQX9b/257/, which gives a bit more flexibility on working this into layouts. Tested in FF, IE7-10...

Comment: This might actually be the only way to get `vertical-align` working in a `position: absolute` element: all my other attempts using `table-cell` don't pick up the height. Best answer on the page I reckon!

Comment: One more note: you can use this with any `display:block` content in place of the image, and it also all works when nested inside responsive fixed-aspect-ratio elements. [Here's an example of both of these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20196938/568458) that also demonstrates another possible approach to multiple-line wrapped text. Downside: the markup starts to get a bit complicated...

Comment: Buddy, you saved my day big time! :) This sounds like the best solution without all those crappy margin hacks.. Great job!

Comment: Hmmm... that helper div seems to be critical. Why is that? PS: This is amazing! So much easier than any other way of doing this.

Comment: Ahhh... whitespace, damn you. I always forget about inline-block and whitespace.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the other answers here, the [CSS3 flexible box model](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/) will, amongst other things, allow you to achieve this.

You only need a single container element. Everything inside it will be laid out according to the flexible box model rules.

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="/logo.png"/>
</div>
```

The CSS is pretty simple, actually:

```
.container { 
    display: box;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    box-pack: center;
    box-align: center;
}
```

I've omitted vendor-prefixed rules for brevity.

Here's a demo in which the img is always in the centre of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/zn8bm/

Note that Flexbox is a fledgling specification, and is only currently implemented in Safari, Chrome and Firefox 4+.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend this solution by Bruno: http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html

However, I ran into a problem w/ his solution w/r/t webkit. It appears that webkit was rendering a small space at the top of the `div` if the empty `span` was allowed to be there. So, for my solution I only add the empty span if I detect the browser to be IE (If someone figures out how to get rid of the space, let me know!) So, my solution ends up being:

---

HTML:

```
<div class="outerdiv">
    <img src="..." /> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outerdiv {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.ie_vertical_align * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.ie_vertical_align span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    width: 0;
}
```

And if I detect the browser to be IE I add an empty span element before the `img` tag and a css style so it looks like:

```
<div class="outerdiv ie_vertical_align">
    <span></span>
    <img src="..." /> 
</div>
```

---

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfvAw/) with this code.

Comment: I am a bit confused. You're using width: 200px; height: 150px; where these numbers come from? What to do if I don't know the size of the image?

Comment: Well, those numbers are just arbitrary bounds for the outer container. Looking at your site, the numbers would probably be the size of the window, i.e. width: 100%, height: 100%.

Answer (score 2):

Dušan Janovský, Czech web developer, has published a cross-browser solution for this some time ago. Read http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Comment: This either requires IE hacks or multiple nested `div`s. Which all suck.

Comment: +1 - @Rikudo Sennin, the article was written in 2004 and updated in 2008. I haven't tested it, but I think with IE8/9 those hacks are no longer necessary.

Comment: Only IE7 and 6 are unfortunately not gone yet, and the OP hasn't stated whether he wanted those or not.

Comment: @Rikudo Sennin The need of nested elements and some CSS hacks for older browsers is, more or less, expected limitation. No simpler code/markup can be used to meet all the OP's requirements. If support for IE6/IE7 is not necessary, the hacks can simply be omitted (just a reminder: it was *you* who said that the reasonable way should be cross-browser); with the use of conditional comments or so, your CSS can validate. Please think about whether your -1 are legitimate. It's not about that I'm interested in what reputation I have, but you can confuse OP by marking suitable answers as "not useful".

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about IE7 and below, you don't have to use multiple nested divs. If you have a div that you want to align vertically, that div is within some container (even if the container is your `<body>`). Therefore, you can specify `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` on the container, and then your div will be vertically centered.

However, if you do care about IE7 and below, you will need an additional container to make it work (yes, via a hack).

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gsKb/9/). It displays correctly in IE6-9 and other major browsers. `#container2` is present solely for IE7 and below, so if you don't care about them, you can remove it as well as the IE-specific conditional styles.

Answer (score 0):

Set the image as background of the div and align it center

Answer (score 0):

try the 50% padding trick:

```
<html>

<body style="width:50%; height: 50%;">
<div style="display:block; display:inline-block; layout-grid:line; 
     text-align:center; vertical-align:bottom; 
     padding: 50% 0 50% 0">test</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is possible if you know the height of the image or flash object to be centered.  You don't need to know the container's height/width, but you do need to know the contained height/width.

It's possible using float, clear and negative margins.  Example: [www.laurenackley.com](http://www.laurenackley.com) homepage.

**html**

```
<div id='container'><!-- container can be BODY -->
  <div id='vertical-center'>&nbsp;</div>
  <div id='contained-with-known-height'>
    <p>stuff</p>
  </div>  
</div>
```

**css**

```
#vertical-center{
  height:50%;
  width:1px;
  float:left;
  margin-bottom:-50px;/** 1/2 of inner div's known height **/
}

#contained-with-known-height{
  height:100px;
  clear:left;
  margin:0 auto;/** horizontal center **/
  width:700px;
  text-align:left;
}
#container{/** or body **/
  text-align:center;
  /** width and height unknown **/
}
```

If you don't know the inner elements width/height.  You are out of luck with `<div>`.  BUT -- **table cells** (`<td>`) do support `vertical-align:middle;`  If you can't get it done with the div stuff above, go with a table inside the container, and put the div you are centering inside a td with vertical-align middle.

Comment: Read the question. He doesn't want to align the contents within the div, he wants to align the div itself.

Comment: i did read the question, the "div itself" in this example would be #contained-with-known-height -- assuming that the contents are of known height, and the container is the unknown.  the question and comments do not clarify which is the unknown or if its both.  which is why i addressed that underneath the example.  read my answer.

Comment: but he stated he **doesn't know the width or the height** so that solution is practically useless.

Comment: i'd disagree with that.  tables serve a purpose, and you don't have to be a purist with divs.  how about a table within a div layout??  sounds like that vertical align property might come in handy, no?

Comment: if he doesn't know the width or the height of the container, this solution is perfect.  if he doesn't know the width or height of the contained, then he should use a table, or javascript.  as stated above, the unknown was not clarified, even though kizu asked, there was no clarification given

Comment: tables are there for one thing, to present data that comes in a table, not to layout your code because it's easier. It's not semantic, and it might effect the page's performance and search engine ranking.

Comment: considering he's looking for help on a flash page, i really doubt search engine ranking is relevant, and a single table with 1 cell is hardly going to "effect the page's performance" -- besides, table discussion is hardly relevant anyway, since judging by the example page he gave, he does seem to know the flash object's height/width at page load, and could therefore utilize the 1st CSS soultion i've offered.