# Vertically center align a div within anothe div

Tags: javascript, css, html, vertical-alignment

say i have

```
<div id ="outer" class="outer">
    <div id= "inner" class="inner">
      //some stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

the inner div has a dynamic height, it changes depending on what is inside the div. the outer div is just a container which is set to have the height of the window.

I want to set it so that the inner div is vertically centered within the outer div. Is there a way to do this easily in CSS or is JavaScript necessary?

***THE SOLUTION I FOUND:***

```
var container= document.getElementById("outer");
var inner= document.getElementById("inner");
var inHeight=inner.offsetHeight;

container.style.height=(window.innerHeight-10);
container.style.width=window.innerWidth;

var conHeight=container.offsetHeight;

inner.style.marginTop=((conHeight-inHeight)/2);
```

In case anyone else searching for a solution to the same problem, this worked for me.

*emphasized text*

Comment: Related question with some useful suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206640/css-vertically-align-div-when-no-fixed-size-of-the-div-is-known

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this out http://jsfiddle.net/gLChk/12/

but it won't be supported in IE<8 browsers. To make it work on all the browsers, you'll have to write a js which will find the height of .inner and apply these css properties

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var inner = $('.inner'),
    ht = inner.height();

inner.css({'position':'absolute','top':'50%','margin':-ht/2+'px 0 0 0'});
});
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: i think i did pretty much the same thing only using JS instead of JQuery. see my question. I added the solution I came up with.

Comment: Oh...well I didn't see your updated answer...well that'll work too. :)

Comment: literally doing the same thing but just in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
.outer {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    border:1px red solid;
}
.inner {
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it with

```
.inner {
top: 50%;
bottom: 50%;    
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLChk/)

greets

Comment: With this method wouldn't you need to subtract the height of the inner div / 2 from 50% to get the 'exact' vetical centering?

Comment: if you check it properly, its not exactly vertically in middle.

Answer (score -3):

use:

```
.inner
{
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
}
```

Comment: i actually think this will work... but it turns out that my outer div is not set to the height and width of the window....