# css vertically centering a fixed positioning div

Tags: css

I have the following HTML for a sort-of lightbox project.

```
<div id="lightbox">
  <img id="image" src="" />
</div>
```

that is using the following CSS:

```
#lightbox{
display:none;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
z-index:600;
cursor:pointer;
left:0;
top:100px;
}

#image{
position:relative;
height:600px;
border:1px solid grey;
}
```

To have the image always in the horizontal center, I am simply using text-align:center on the wrapper div, so I am 100% sure it will be correct.

I am facing problems with the vertical centering and I am using a workaround of simply setting the top value in the #lightbox properties.

As you can see the height of the image is known, so it is easily doable in jQuery but I am looking for a pure CSS solution.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: "so I am 100% sure it will be correct" ?? What if your image is display:block ?

Comment: it's not. it's either inline or none.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Alternatively, you could try this (only works if you know the height of the image):

```
#image{
position:relative;
height:600px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -300px; /* minus half the height */
border:1px solid grey;
}
```

Comment: simplest solution when you have a known height!

Comment: use 'transform: translateY(-50%);' and drop the 'margin-top: -300px' to get this to work for any height

Answer (score 160):

The best solution I've seen for both vertically and horizontally centering a `position: fixed` `div` is:

```
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vincentpace/jak84zrx/215/) and [source](http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/). You don't need to know the dimensions of the `div` and it doesn't require any container `div`s. The centered `div`'s width can even be a percentage (which was what I was looking for when I found this solution).

Comment: Fantastic solution if you are not plannig to support IE8.

Comment: If the element you are centering contains text, this will cause the text to become blurry since the use of translate activates 3d hardware acceleration.

Comment: @Gyro Is there any fix for that blurry effect?

Comment: I only know a solution in webkit, with css property -webkit-font-smoothing

Comment: `position: absolute` makes test **not-blurry** in _Chrome_

Answer (score 7):

Here are couple SASS mixins I'm using... I hope this is going to help someone:

```
// vertically centers as relative
@mixin vertical-align {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}


// vertically centers the element as absolute
@mixin vertical-center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}


// horizontally centers the element as absolute
@mixin horizontal-center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}


// absolutely centers the element inside of its first non-static parent
@mixin absolute-center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer as it doesn't rely on the height of the element. By using transform: translateY(-50%) this works regardless of height

Comment: Curious, why is the `translateY(-50%)` needed when you already specified `top: 50%`?

Answer (score 6):

Use a combo of CSS3's viewport units and calc( ) to center a lightbox without the risk of blurring text due to hardware acceleration. This solution is also responsive. Convert the formula
`margin-top = -height / 2` from fixed units to viewport units

```
/* Overlay */
body::after
{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 19000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    display: block;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    content: ' ';

    opacity: .2;
    background-color: #000;
}

/* Lightbox */
.lightbox
{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 15;
    top: 50%;
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vh;
    margin: 0 5vw;
    margin-top: calc(-90vh / 2 );
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wtalexy/v4wozv1r/13/)

More information on relative length units and calc( ):

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

**Detailed Example**

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
/* The Overlay */
 body::after {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 14;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content:' ';
    opacity: .5;
    background-color: #000;
}
/* The Lightbox */
 .lightbox{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 15;
    top: 50%;
    width: 60vw;
    height: 60vh;
    margin: 0 20vw;
    margin-top: calc(-60vh / 2);
    background:#fff;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Bonus: responsive and centered image */
 .lightbox h1 {
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
     position: relative;
     padding-left: 1em;
     font-family: sans-serif;
     color: #E2E8F2;
 }
.highlight
{
    color: #4E2622;
}
 .lightbox img {
    max-width: 120%;
    height: auto;
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="lightbox">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CMSrIg_XAAAQU3a.jpg:large">
        <h1><span class="highlight">Sono</span> Neko その猫</h1>
</div>

<h1>Leave dead animals as gifts</h1>


<h3>Meowwww missing until dinner time</h3>

<p>Cat ipsum dolor sit amet, vommit food and eat it again. Find something else more interesting favor packaging over toy yet hide at bottom of staircase to trip human or intently stare at the same spot, but poop in litter box, scratch the walls attack feet ears back wide eyed. Scratch leg; meow for can opener to feed me. Where is my slave? i'm getting hungry purr for no reason or eat a plant, kill a hand eat a plant, kill a hand. Where is my slave? i'm getting hungry jump around on couch, meow constantly until given food, , so chase dog then run away yet stick butt in face, for poop on grasses for rub face on owner, under the bed. Brown cats with pink ears meow destroy the blinds why must they do that, and see owner, run in terror. Meowing non stop for food play time, yet stand in front of the computer screen get video posted to internet for chasing red dot poop in litter box, scratch the walls. Destroy couch leave dead animals as gifts why must they do that, for find something else more interesting hopped up on catnip sleep in the bathroom sink. Kitty power! pooping rainbow while flying in a toasted bread costume in space eat grass, throw it back up and spread kitty litter all over house. I like big cats and i can not lie. Under the bed brown cats with pink ears loves cheeseburgers has closed eyes but still sees you yet chase red laser dot. Claw drapes drink water out of the faucet and behind the couch refuse to leave cardboard box but hunt anything that moves. Rub face on owner favor packaging over toy yet play time. Hide when guests come over love to play with owner's hair tie. Purr for no reason make meme, make cute face eat a plant, kill a hand all of a sudden cat goes crazy, or stare at the wall, play with food and get confused by dust for hate dog love to play with owner's hair tie. Sleep on keyboard eat grass, throw it back up but hopped up on catnip make meme, make cute face. Pooping rainbow while flying in a toasted bread costume in space. Chase imaginary bugs destroy the blinds claws in your leg for hack up furballs. I am the best chase laser but i am the best yet meow all night having their mate disturbing sleeping humans and hunt by meowing loudly at 5am next to human slave food dispenser. Destroy the blinds. Eat a plant, kill a hand run in circles, and chew iPad power cord, and rub face on everything, and sit in box mark territory, so ignore the squirrels, you'll never catch them anyway. Present belly, scratch hand when stroked nap all day, and spot something, big eyes, big eyes, crouch, shake butt, prepare to pounce destroy couch, but put toy mouse in food bowl run out of litter box at full speed .</p>
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the image to have a fluid size, you can use the height of the view as a reference:

```
#img {
   position: relative; /* or absolute or fixed depending on your needs */
   top: 50%;
   height: 80vh;
   margin-top: -40vh; /* minus half the height */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What **solved** for me is to **add an empty super parent** with those properties, from there --> each child or sub-child will be vertically and horizontally centered.

**If you need only horizontally/vertically** remove the unnecessary properties as I wrote in the code-comments.

CSS:

```
.page-area{
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 5;/*not must but usually fixed elements require to be top*/
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;/*define the horizontally centering*/
      align-items: center;/*define the vertically centering*/
    }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class = "page-area">
    <div>My centered element/s</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

To vertically center an item you need the following 2 css attributes :

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
```

example : http://jsfiddle.net/yjv94/

Comment: Apply it to #lightbox see my example.

Comment: @Ladineko : this will apply to an inline and not floating element
Also, The vertical-align property affects the vertical positioning inside a line box of the boxes generated by an inline-level element.

Answer (score -2):

have you check this soution?:

[CSS: Vertically align div when no fixed size of the div is known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206640/css-vertically-align-div-when-no-fixed-size-of-the-div-is-known)

here you dont need to have a height declared.

Regards