# Center a div both vertically and horizontally using margin auto

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to display a block in the center of the window using margin auto.

My code is

```
<div class="centre-element"> This box is coming at the center of the window. </div>
```

CSS

```
.centre-element{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

This works in all the browsers I tested except in IE7. Is there any help for this?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: Vertically align div when no fixed size of the div is known](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206640/css-vertically-align-div-when-no-fixed-size-of-the-div-is-known)

Answer (score 2):

you can't center a `div` vertically using `margin: auto`, but you could try this:

```
.centre-element {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px; /* height/2 */
}
```

**Edit:**

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZD432/

Comment: You are almost there. Do same thing with left: `left: 50%; margin-left: -100px`. +1 anyway :)

Comment: @Morpheus - No need to do the same thing with "left" as "margin:0 auto;" will do the trick.

Comment: @Billy Moat if `margin:0 auto;` will be added **before** `margin-top: -50px`

Comment: @Morpheus Billy Moat's right. And you could use:  `margin: -50px auto 0;`

Comment: [This is proof that you both are not right](http://jsfiddle.net/8uZCD/). [And this is how it should be](http://jsfiddle.net/8uZCD/1/)

Comment: @Morpheus you're right in one way...   But Rupam Datta used `position:absolute; left:0; right:0;` so in this case you can use `margin: -50px auto 0;` (and in this way you'll have a dynamic width to)

Comment: @Barnee please post the complete answer with [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) example

Comment: @Barnee Thanks for your solution. But as Morpheus said, I have to use left: 50% and margin-left: -100px to get it worked completely.

Answer (score 0):

```
.centre-element{
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   margin: auto;
   padding: auto;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Morpheus. I usually use above code to bring a div in center of the window(horizontally). But your comment made my concept more clear about margin and padding.