# Center align vertically

Tags: css

I have a common problem, although I have not been able to solve it with solutions found elsewehere on Stack Overflow. I'm trying to vertically align a logo and a search bar overlayed on an image in a header with unknown height (since the image shrinks when browser width decreases, since it's responsive)

The challenges are:

1. I have a header image (img, not a CSS background image) in one div block and a logo & search bar in two other div blocks that need to be overlayed on the background image.
2. The header image will shrink in size as browse width decreases, as it's a responsive site. That means I don't know the height of the header.
3. The logo is to be floated left and the search bar to the right.
4. I need to somehow center the logo and search bar vertically, so that they always appear nicely, regardless of the height of the header image that they are overlayed on.

Example: http://www-dev.channelaustin.org/about

Any suggestion?

Comment: Won't happen without scripting, but you already knew that. If it is a truly responsive site, you can reduce the logo and header sizes in steps rather than fluidly. Then you'd be able to get vertical centering.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I'll have to do it this way after all.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206640/css-vertically-align-div-when-no-fixed-size-of-the-div-is-known), essentially answers your question. As you only want vertical centring, you should remove the:

```
top: 50%;
```

Comment: Thanks. However, using this solution makes the height of the div 2000px, as we don't know the height of its container. So it still centers vertically only within the height of its container.

Comment: @Daniel Westergren, The user describes it as working without knowing the height one the container, you could remove the height: 2000px; line.