# Vertically align an inline-block in a div with a fixed height

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxbKwW)

I want to align the  both vertically and horizontally, the height and width of the container will be fixed regarding other extenal factors.

How do i do that?

I've tried using flex

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
```

but it gets rid of my horizontal alignment

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: Vertically align div when no fixed size of the div is known](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206640/css-vertically-align-div-when-no-fixed-size-of-the-div-is-known)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there are [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474#18516474) [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3/25517025#25517025) to achieve vertical alignment, here is one:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

a {
  width: 100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;  
  font-size: 16px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">Some Text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! just before your reply I found the answer using position:relative; and position:absolute;

Comment: @Pontiacks You're welcome. Yes, as I mentioned there are couple of ways, but I assumed you want to keep the element in normal flow as an `inline-block` element which is stated clearly in the title of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

On the div parent:

```
position:relative;
```

On the a child:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -half_its_width;
margin-top: -half_his_height;
```